# inline image not moving down on overflow line-break

Tags: css, overflow, image, css-position, line-breaks

I have an inline image in my div that is inline by using `position:absolute` (I can't use other methods for inline because they cause the line-height to change.) These images flow out of the div and are sent to the next line... but the image doesn't go down.. it is sent to the next line meaning it is sent to the far left of the div but it doesn't move down in height so it's almost like it stays on the same line but moves to the left? How can I fix this?

Example: (*Change the width of the last **TWO** images from 30px to 150px to see the effect I'm describing.) http://jsfiddle.net/ztKP5/2/

---

Code: (*Change the width of the last **TWO** images from 30px to 150px to see the effect I'm describing.)

```
<div style="font: 30px; border:1px solid black; width: 350px; height:350px; word-wrap: break-word;">

<font face='helvetica'>

Test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test!!

<img src='http://home.comcast.net/~urbanjost/images/globe_west_2048.jpg' style='width: 100px; height: 75px; position:absolute;'>
<img src='' style='width:100px; height:2px;'> <!-- this is a spacer-->

<img src='http://home.comcast.net/~urbanjost/images/globe_west_2048.jpg' style='width: 30px; height: 75px; position:absolute;'>
<img src='' style='width:30px; height:2px;'> <!-- this is a spacer-->


</font>

</div>
```

Comment: The second and fourth images are just spacers so that the next text, or image, or whatever will appear after the absolutely positions image instead of behind it... I could have used an in-line div or a span or anything...

Comment: Position absolute does not make an element inline. I am also unclear on exactly it is that you would like to do.

Comment: It makes the image inline without changing the line height. If you just use the inline property the paragraphs line-height changes.

Comment: If you look at my code and run it and then you change the width of the last two images to 150px you will see that they overflow and are therefor sent to the next line... the problem is they aren't going down they are just flying to the left side of the div. When things go to the next line they fly to the left side (the beginning) but they also move down the line-height... These stay in the same "y" position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping the **absolute positioned** image in a div that was `display:inline-block` (... **NOT** `display:inline`) fixed the problem.

Add an extra "!" after the "test" text to see here: http://jsfiddle.net/Z9rzx/2/

Or add an extra "!" after the "test" text in the source code below to see the image go to the next line:

```
<!--The second and fourth images are just spacers so that the next text, or image, or whatever will appear after the absolutely positions image instead of behind it... I could have used an in-line div or a span or anything...-->


<div style="font: 30px; border:1px solid black; width: 350px; height:350px; word-wrap: break-word;">

<font face='helvetica'>

Test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test!!!!!!!!

<div style="width:100px; display:inline-block;">
  <img src='http://home.comcast.net/~urbanjost/images/globe_west_2048.jpg' style='width: 100px; position:absolute;'>
  <img src='' style='width: 100px; height:2px;'>
</div>

<div style="width:100px; display:inline-block;">
  <img src='http://home.comcast.net/~urbanjost/images/globe_west_2048.jpg' style='width: 100px; position:absolute;'>
  <img src='' style='width: 100px; height:2px;'>
</div>

test tast test test test test test test test test test test


</font>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked at this cross browser, but it works in firefox.
http://jsfiddle.net/digitalagua/NeX4A/

```
<style>
.holder {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    border:1px solid black;
    width: 350px;
    height:350px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    display:inline-block;
}

.floater {
    width: 150px; height: 75px;margin-bottom:-63px;
}
<style>

<div class="holder">

Test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test!!

<img src="http://home.comcast.net/~urbanjost/images/globe_west_2048.jpg" class="floater">
Test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test!!

<img src="http://home.comcast.net/~urbanjost/images/globe_west_2048.jpg" class="floater">
Test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test!!

</div>
```

Comment: Yes!!!! But do you have any idea how to get the image above the text?

http://jsfiddle.net/Z9rzx/1/

Comment: Can you post an image of what you are after?

Comment: Exactly what is here: http://jsfiddle.net/Z9rzx/1/  Except I need the image in front of the text.

Comment: I like your new code... unfortunately I know can't move the images or along them vertically, in the middle, and what-not because the images position is not absolute... I found a solution that I posted above though that allows for this O:) Thankyou for your help! +1